# Javascript spread operator in Clojurescript?

Tags: clojurescript

I am trying to achieve the following javascript code in clojurescript:

```js
const a = {
   "foo": "bar",
   //...
};

let b = {
    ...a,
  //^ what is the clojurescript equivalent for this?
    "newprop": 10,
};
```

I have tried to `assoc-in`, thinking it would behave like a clojure map, with no success...

Comment: If you haven't seen it, be sure to checkout the ClojureScript CheatSheet!  https://cljs.info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My question was not clear enough, I had an object `defaultProps` coming from an external js library. My goal was to create a new instance of this js object and extending it with new props, and feeding it back to a js function expecting a js object. There was more to it than I first foresaw. I finally managed to do it with some juggling with `js->clj` and `clj->js`:

```
(def b
    (clj->js (assoc (js->clj a) "newprop" 10)))
```

Thank you for your answers!

Comment: To "spread" more than one param you might also want to consider using `into`.

Answer (score 2):

To provide you with another option, you can use [`goog.object`](https://google.github.io/closure-library/api/goog.object.html) to interact with JavaScript objects in ClojureScript. The following code will work:

```
(require 'goog.object)

(def a #js {:foo "bar"})

;; Modify `a` inline
(goog.object/set a "newprop" 10) ;; In JS, this is equivalent to a.newprop = 10
```

If you want to do a shallow copy of `a` and modify that value, you can use `clone` (which will behave like the spread operator).

```
;; Shallow copy a
(def b (goog.object/clone a))

;; Modify the cloned object
(goog.object/set b "newprop" 10)
```

There's a neat library you can use though to interact with JavaScript objects if you need to do it often: https://github.com/binaryage/cljs-oops

Answer (score 0):

```
(def a {:foo "bar"})
(def b (assoc a :newProp 10))
```

Comment: Sorry I was not clear enough, a is actually a constant defined by a js library

Comment: Nvm js->clj seems to be what I'm looking for

Answer (score 0):

This is really just combining two maps together. That can be done with [`merge`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/merge):

```
(def a {"foo" "bar"})  ; Emulating the constant
(def b {"newprop" 10})

(def c (merge a b))  ; {"foo" "bar", "newprop" 10}
```